# How to use Robolectric 2.4 in Android Studio 1.1.0 & gradle 2.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, robolectric

I am unable to configure my Android Studio Project with Robolectric. Could any one guide me step by step to build an android studio 1.1.0 project with Robolectric 2.4 & gradle 2.2.1

This sample projects work fine https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle. But I am not able to implement it in my existing Android Studio projects.

//below are the detailed description

---

//Contents Of of project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

---

//Contents Of app/src/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "robo.testing.android.testrobo08"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java'] } }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

    // Test Compile
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
}
```

---

//Contents Of MainActivityTest

```
package robo.testing.android.testrobo08.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.Robolectric;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;

import robo.testing.android.testrobo08.MainActivity;
import robo.testing.android.testrobo08.R;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

/**
 * Created by cflap584 on 13/3/15.
 */

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest = "./src/main/AndroidManifest.xml", emulateSdk = 18)

public class MainActivityTest {
    Activity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().get();

    TextView textView = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

    @Test
    public void testTextView_lableName() throws Exception {
        String actual = textView.getText().toString();
        assertThat("Hello World!", equalTo(actual));
    }


}
```

---

//ERROR

```
robo.testing.android.testrobo08.test.MainActivityTest > testTextView_lableName STANDARD_ERROR
    WARNING: no system properties value for ro.build.date.utc

robo.testing.android.testrobo08.test.MainActivityTest > testTextView_lableName STANDARD_OUT
    DEBUG: Loading resources for robo.testing.android.testrobo08 from ././src/main/res...
    DEBUG: Loading resources for android from jar:/home/cflap584/.m2/repository/org/robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/android-all-4.3_r2-robolectric-0.jar!/res...
Gradle Test Executor 1 finished executing tests.

robo.testing.android.testrobo08.test.MainActivityTest > testTextView_lableName FAILED
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find any resource  from reference ResName{robo.testing.android.testrobo08:style/Theme_AppCompat_Light_DarkActionBar} from style StyleData{name='AppTheme', parent='Theme_AppCompat_Light_DarkActionBar'} with theme null
        at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager$StyleResolver.getParent(ShadowAssetManager.java:456)
        at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager$StyleResolver.getAttrValue(ShadowAssetManager.java:394)
        at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.getOverlayedThemeValue(ShadowResources.java:294)
        at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.findAttributeValue(ShadowResources.java:283)
        at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.attrsToTypedArray(ShadowResources.java:186)
        at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.access$000(ShadowResources.java:44)
        at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources$ShadowTheme.obtainStyledAttributes(ShadowResources.java:491)
        at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources$ShadowTheme.obtainStyledAttributes(ShadowResources.java:486)
        at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources$ShadowTheme.obtainStyledAttributes(ShadowResources.java:481)
        at android.content.res.Resources$Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources.java)
        at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:380)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:147)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:138)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
        at robo.testing.android.testrobo08.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
        at org.robolectric.internal.ReflectionHelpers$3.run(ReflectionHelpers.java:64)
        at org.robolectric.internal.ReflectionHelpers.traverseClassHierarchy(ReflectionHelpers.java:114)
        at org.robolectric.internal.ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethodReflectively(ReflectionHelpers.java:59)
        at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:115)
        at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:268)
        at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:111)
        at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:122)
        at robo.testing.android.testrobo08.test.MainActivityTest.<init>(MainActivityTest.java:26)
```

Comment: What exact problem do you have? Any error logs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## I found the problem. In my case it was not able to find the AndroidManifest.xml file & i haven't use customRobolectricTestRunner.

## Project Structure

```
  Gradle Version 2.2.1
  Android Plugin Version 1.1.0
```

## project build.gradle file's content

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

## App build.gradle file's content

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "robo.testing.android.testrobo"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 18
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java'] } }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'


// Test Compile
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
}
```

## Build Variants

```
Test Artificat : Unit Tests
```

I found some reference for my solution
https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1592
@erd If you are using Gradle / Android Studio, you need to create a custom test runner that will tell Robolectric where to find your merged assets, resources, and manifest. Please see the discussion here:

http://nenick-android.blogspot.in/2015/03/android-studio-110-and-robolectric-30.html

## content of src/test/java/packageName.test/CustomRobolectricRunner.java

```
 public CustomRobolectricRunner(Class<?> testClass)
            throws InitializationError {
        super(testClass);
        String buildVariant = (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.isEmpty()
                ? "" : BuildConfig.FLAVOR+ "/") + BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE;
        String intermediatesPath = BuildConfig.class.getResource("")
                .toString().replace("file:", "");
        intermediatesPath = intermediatesPath
                .substring(0, intermediatesPath.indexOf("/classes"));

        System.setProperty("android.package", 
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
        System.setProperty("android.manifest",
                intermediatesPath + "/manifests/full/" 
                        + buildVariant + "/AndroidManifest.xml");
        System.setProperty("android.resources", 
                intermediatesPath + "/res/" + buildVariant);
        System.setProperty("android.assets", 
                intermediatesPath + "/assets/" + buildVariant);
    }
```

## Content of MainActivityTest.java

```
package robo.testing.android.testrobo.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.Robolectric;

import robo.testing.android.testrobo.MainActivity;
import robo.testing.android.testrobo.R;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual.equalTo;

/**
 * Created by cflap584 on 16/3/15.
 */

@RunWith(CustomRobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MainActivityTest {
    Activity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().get();
    TextView textView = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

    @Test
    public void testTextView_labelName() throws Exception {
        String actual = textView.getText().toString();
        assertThat("Hello world!", equalTo(actual));

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: I do not think you need this: `sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java'] } }`. Also, have you tried this with `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'`?

Comment: @JaredBurrows yeah its working with classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3' sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java'] } } was added by default

Comment: Thanks for solving this. What a pain, I want Robolectrie 3.0 to finally be out for Android 21 support.

Comment: @avinashkumar how you run tests?

Comment: @andreich  you can run your test by simply select your TestClass file and right click on it, it will give you an option to Run as TestClass. Here TestClass is your class file name where you have written Test. Other method is  executing this command "./gradlew test" in your terminal. After executing you can see the report /app/build/report/tests/debug/index.html

Comment: @avinashkumar I run tests with Gradle command testDebug and tests are run and pass, but the result is not displayed as your screenshot

Comment: @andreich when you use gradle command it wont display like i posted as screenshot. For that you have to run by right click on your testClass file. Or you can choose Menu -> Run -> Edit Configuration add New configuration by clicking + sign and choose as Android Test. Give a name to your configuration and while you running choose this test configuration.